# SQL Get All Categories And All Sub Categories

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Can you help me to get all categories with all sub categories like that ?

[image]

**Database Creation Script**

```
CREATE TABLE Category(Id INT NOT NULL, ParentId INT NULL)
GO
INSERT INTO Category (Id, ParentId) VALUES (1, NULL)
INSERT INTO Category (Id, ParentId) VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO Category (Id, ParentId) VALUES (3, 1)
INSERT INTO Category (Id, ParentId) VALUES (4, 2)
INSERT INTO Category (Id, ParentId) VALUES (5, 2)
INSERT INTO Category (Id, ParentId) VALUES (6, 2)
GO
```

I tried in ms-sql to solve that with using cursor technique and join method but can get all data.

```
SELECT parent.Id AS ParentId, parent.ParentId AS ChildId FROM Category parent
JOIN Category child ON parent.Id = child.Id
```

**Expecting Result**

```
ParentId    ChildId
----------- -----------
1           1
1           2
1           3
1           4
1           5
1           6
2           2
2           4
2           5
2           6
3           3
4           4
5           5
6           6
```

Thank You

Comment: Could you post your code and show what you have tried?  Moreover, could you tag which RDMS you are using, oracle, sql-server or others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: also what is the logic behind category-subcategory pairs?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+recursive-query

Comment: I'm tring to solve in ms sql and yes it it recursive. But 1 "category one" shound have 1,2,3,4,5,6 childs in my senario, thanks.

Comment: just do two self-joins

Comment: Could you share a sample plase. @RadimBača

Comment: It is not duplicate of your link @DariaPydorenko, my expecting output is different. For Expample, one should have 6 childs in my case, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to alter the database schema? such as adding two extra columns with pre-computed values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT * , Id AS TopLevelParent
    FROM dbo.Category c

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.* , r.TopLevelParent
    FROM dbo.Category c
    INNER JOIN RCTE r ON c.ParentId = r.Id
)
SELECT 
  r.TopLevelParent AS ParentID
, r.Id AS ChildID 
FROM RCTE r
ORDER BY ParentID;
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34d4fd/1)**

Comment: Thank you sir, it returns expected output result.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, you need a recursive CTE for this. One thing that makes this one a bit trickier is the fact you essentially are transforming ID (int) into character data (-).

I believe the below query will get you started for the desired results. This does not take into account that you want to essentially list all children, regardless of their spot in the hierarchy, though.

```
WITH CategoryTree AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID AS CategoryID
        , CAST(ID AS varchar(50)) AS CatVar
        , 0 AS LeafLevel    
        , ParentID
    FROM Category WHERE ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        ID AS CategoryID 
        , CAST(CONCAT(CAST(Category.ParentID AS varchar), '-', CAST(Id AS varchar)) AS varchar(50)) AS CatVar
        , CategoryTree.LeafLevel + 1 AS LeafLevel   
        , Category.ParentID
    FROM Category 
        JOIN CategoryTree ON Category.ParentId = CategoryTree.CategoryId
    WHERE Category.ParentID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * FROM CategoryTree
```

Output:

```
CategoryID  CatVar  LeafLevel   ParentID
1           1       0           NULL
2           1-2     1           1
3           1-3     1           1
4           2-4     2           2
5           2-5     2           2
6           2-6     2           2
```

Comment: Hello, your result is not same as my expecting result output but thank you for your help.

Comment: @SaygınKarahan - you can try changing his query around to see how it affects the results. It will also help you understand how it works. Hint: try removing `WHERE ParentID IS NULL` from `FROM Category WHERE ParentID IS NULL`

Comment: @SaygınKarahan - you have tagged the question SQL Server 2008 - but your comment infers this runs fine for you; this answer uses the CONCAT function which wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2012. Which version are you actually running?